# How to identify fresh pork liver?

Tags: meat, pork, ingredient-selection, shopping, liver

I cook pork liver very often.

Sometimes when grocery shopping, I find pork liver that's kind pale in color and with not much blood. Other times, I find liver that's very red and full of blood.

Is fresh, good pork liver supposed to be darker/redder with a lot of blood?

Comment: In chickens, the color of the liver is primarily determined by diet: factory-confined chickens, fed mostly on grain, have a fatty and light-colored liver while free-range chickens, eating a mixture of grain, plants, and insects, have lean and dark-colored livers. I don't know whether this applies to pigs.

Answer (score 1):

When purchasing pork liver, look for these signs of freshness and quality:

Color: The liver should have a rich, reddish-brown color, though it may vary slightly. Avoid liver that appears pale or discolored.

Texture: The liver should have a smooth texture and feel slightly firm when touched. Avoid a liver that feels slimy, excessively soft, or mushy.

Odor: Fresh pork liver should have a mild, earthy odor. Avoid liver with a strong, unpleasant smell, as it may indicate spoilage.

Blood content: While small traces of blood are normal, excessive blood or a liver that appears overly bloody might indicate issues with freshness or handling.

Hope this Helps